# Ignore all files with given name and extension

Tags: git, gitignore

I would like git to ignore any files called `manifest` with an extension of `csv` that are found anywhere within `app/assets`recursively, including subfolders at any depth.

For example:

```
app/assets/manifest.csv
app/assets/foo/manifest.csv
app/assets/foo/bar/manifest.csv
```

What rule should I add to my `.gitignore`?

From suggestions in answers I've tried:

```
app/assets/**/manifest.csv
```

But this doesn't ignore them. targeting them individually does, for example:

```
app/assets/images/placeholder/manifest.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding:

```
app/assets/**/manifest.csv
```

Per `gitignore` documentation:

```
A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash
matches zero or more directories.

For example, "a/**/b" matches "a/b", "a/x/b", "a/x/y/b" and so on.
```

Comment: That would make sense, but it doesn't work. 
`app/assets/**/manifest.csv` doesn't ignore, but `app/assets/images/placeholder/manifest.csv` does.

Comment: See Charles Bailey's answer. Your version of git may not support `**`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19711792

Answer (score 2):

In `app/assets/.gitignore` put the pattern:

```
manifest.csv
```

This is portable to older Git's that only support standard globbing (no `**`).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might do it:

```
app/assets/**/manifest.csv
```

My best guess from the [Gitignore man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).